# Android App Market Update Propagation

Tags: android

I uploaded a new version of my APK to the android market and "activated" then saved it.  My publisher/home reports that it is my desired version, but the app's download page in the app market is still showing the previous version.  Is there a propagation period?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes there is a propagation period. It can take up to 48 hours for you app to appear on the market. But it's usually much less than that. Keep an eye on it, and if things don't seem to be working in a couple days, contact the people in charge of the market.

Answer (score 2):

Generally it takes a few hours for applications to update on the market, on the rare occasion I haven't seen updates to my applications for 24 hours after publishing via the developer console.

Answer (score 2):

Generally take a few hours between you upload the app and the update apear in the first users (users that init the market app and when the market start check for updates).
The time that the market and the web market take to show the new information is diferent too