# Google Play Alpha|Beta Link cant be found

Tags: android, google-play

I recently published my first application so I did Alpha, the console status is "Published", create a community, I've added people, they have accepted the invitation and received the link.

```
https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.package
```

but after 30-40 minutes the link to download the application is deactivated. my question is I need to do something or how average waiting time for the application is available

this is the link generate by the previous link

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.package
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give it time to propagate within all Google servers, so as a ballpark figure I'd say wait 24hours.

It's like publishing any new website.

This answer actually says 48 hours:

[Android App Market Update Propagation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8173200/android-app-market-update-propagation)

---

Another issue I have noticed with people is, make sure the device they are looking for the link with **is signed in with the same Google Account as accepted the G+ group invite**